# Which scriptures forbid the chanting of beeja mantras without initiation?

Tags: scripture, mantras, vedic-chanting, japa, bijakshara

It is often stated by many that Mantras containing beeja Aksharas should not be chanted without initiation. Are there any scriptures which mention this prohibition? And in case one does happen to chant them without initiation, what adverse effects would that bring? If possible please answer with proper scriptural citation.

Comment: Good question, I'm curious too, I haven't come across something that actually forbids it yet. The possible bad effects are clear and make sense, but that's not really due to lack of initiation, but rather due to imperfect pronunciation, lack of following certain rules and lifestyle practices or due to lack of personal tapa (which initiation solves by the tapa being transferred to you from someone who already has Mantra Siddhi).

Comment: This restriction explicitly comes from scriptures of Shakta like Kalika, Tara etc tantras.

Comment: @Chamundadas Please write an answer by citing the sources. Regards